# present for a fixed plan

Tags: present-tense

My friend wrote me that he is coming in march to see me

Shall I write " happy to see you in march   but a bit sad we **can't see** sooner".

Can I use the present because it is a fixed arrangment or Is it  better to write" sad not to see sooner".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, "can't see" is fine, but you need a reflexive pronoun:

> Happy to see you in March but a bit sad we can't see each other sooner.